# Can entities outside of an event E's light cone be influenced by a proxy entity that is inside the light cone of said event E

Tags: relativity

I apologize upfront if my question is poorly worded but I am trying to understand conceptually events and light cones.

Say for example that there is a celestial body B that I am capable of observing in some measurable fashion.

If this body B is on the edge or boundary of an event E's light cone and I am outside of the light cone for event E then am I able to ascertain any kind of observable influence on the example celestial body B by event E ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The (future) light cone of an event E is the set of points in spacetime that E can send a signal to. If E could influence B in such a way that you could observe that effect on B, then E can send a signal to you. But by assumption you are outside the light cone of E, so this is not possible.